# Not able to write messages into the file in c++?

Tags: c++

Do you see any reason because of which processName won't be written into the sysSettings file, if it's not there?? I don't know why it's not writing there. Please help !!!

```
void pushSysSet(const char* processName)
    {
        char oneLine[15];
        fstream sysSettings;
        sysSettings.open("p_appmanager/src/sys_settings.txt",ios::in | ios:: out | ios::app);
        if(!sysSettings.is_open())
        {
            if(debugFlag)
            {
                cout<<currentTime()<<"::"<<"Unable to open sys_settings file"<<strerror(errno)<<endl;
                cout.flush();
            }
            return;
        }
        while(!((sysSettings.getline(oneLine,sizeof(oneLine))).eof()))
        {
            if(!strcmp(oneLine,processName))
                return;
        }
        sysSettings<<processName;
        sysSettings.flush();
        sysSettings.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use eof() to control a loop. And what's with all the C strings?

```
void pushSysSet(const char* processName)
{
    fstream sysSettings("p_appmanager/src/sys_settings.txt", ios::in | ios::out | ios::app);
    if(!sysSettings)
    {
        if(debugFlag)
        {
            cout<<currentTime()<<"::"<<"Unable to open sys_settings file"<<strerror(errno)<<endl;
            cout.flush();
        }
        return;
    }
    std::string oneLine;
    while(std::getline(sysSettings, oneLine))
    {
        if(oneLine == processName)
            return;
    }
    sysSettings.clear();
    sysSettings << processName << '\n';
}
```

I cleaned up the code a bit. No point in doing separate flush and close before going out of scope if you're not checking the result; that's part of the destructor anyway. Using std::string to get rid of possible buffer overflows or truncated names, and generally to make things nicer. Cleaned up the condition of the while loop.

I also added a newline after the `processName` output: since your reading code apparently expects that thing to be on a line by itself, it's only correct to make sure of that in the writing code.

Finally, as Casey pointed out, once you've read the entire file the stream is in an error state and won't respond to your write, so clear the state first.

Comment: Thank you very much, but one question,  why they have done such implementation?? If I have opened the file in append mode then it should be allowed to write into the file even after the eof flag is set!!

Comment: That's simply not what the append mode does. It just ensures that all output operations append to the file. It doesn't change the fact that a stream in error mode (including eof) does not react to any I/O requests.

Answer (score 1):

Writing `processName` to the stream fails because the `eof` bit is set. Clear the stream's error state flags with `sysSettings.clear()` before writing:

```
while(!((sysSettings.getline(oneLine,sizeof(oneLine))).eof()))
{
        if(!strcmp(oneLine,processName))
            return;
}
sysSettings.clear();
sysSettings<<processName;
```

Comment: but I have opened the fine in "Appand" mode??